# What is the difference between context and namespace?

Tags: namespaces, scope, this, terminology

I've heard these terms numerous times. Frankly speaking I think namespace as an environment which  holds identifiers (and a unique 'value' mapped to it). Context is like a data set much like a `'key' = 'value'` type of mapping. I am confused about these. If anyone can describe these terms more clearly, it will be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably depends on which language you're thinking about, but using some JavaScript as an example:

```
var FOO = {
    bar:function(){
        return this == FOO; //=> true
        }
    };
```

In this case, you could say that **FOO** is a acting like a namespace. While JavaScript doesn't have a formal concept of namespacing, we've defined an object and are using it to compartmentalise a certain peice of code.

A context is usually the environment in which something is being run. In this example, the **bar** function has a context which is referenced by the *this* keyword. When running the function like so:

```
FOO.bar();
```

we're invoking the function within the context of the **FOO** object, so **FOO** gets assigned to *this*. We could run the code under a different context:

```
var BAZ={};
BAZ.bar = FOO.bar;
BAZ.bar();
```

This time the function's context is BAZ, so the return value will be false.

So both terms define some kind of environment, but a namespace is a fixed environment while context may change depending on how the code is being run.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to look at it this way:

A namespace is a container in which you find items that have context.

For example.

Think of a house.

Each bedroom has a bed. Let's say that there is the Master bedroom, the Childs bedroom and a Spare bedroom.

The namespaces here are the names of the bedrooms e.g Master, Child, Spare.

Now the Master bedroom has a Double bed, the Child bedroom a Single bed and the Spare room a Folding bed.

The Double bed only has context within the Master bedroom, the Single bed only within the Child bed room and the Folding bed within the Spare room.

Now all bedrooms have items of Furniture (the bed, dressing table, wardrobe) and these are defined in the Furniture namespace.

If all rooms refer/use the Furniture namespace then Bed, Dressing Table, Wardrobe all have valid contexts within those rooms, BUT a double bed isn't valid within the Child or Spare room.

You could of course put a Folding bed into the Child bedroom in which case it would have context there, although this would be of different context to the Folding bed already in the Spare room.

If you removed a room (say there was a fire) then the furniture that had context within it would also be destroyed e.g. a fire in the Master bedroom would destroy the Double bed, dressing table and wardrobe.

Comment: thanks. Your descriptive, real life example along with the other two programmatic examples explain the concepts nicely.

Answer (score 1):

What you said about `Namespace` is correct, i'll explain you in a programming way coz im not a theory man.

```
namespace SampleNamespace
{
    class foo
    {
          public void run()
         {
           console.writeline("RUN");
         }
    }
}
```

See above Namespace `SampleNamespace` contain a class `foo`, now here namespace is an environment and class is its data, so another Namespace can also contain class 'foo' but same Namespace cannot contain same class. A Namespace can contain n number of identifiers, its like organising your programs to avoid having classes with same name.

**Context** : it is far different than Namespace, it is not an environment but it defines an environment for objects. So you can say context is a collection of properties that defines an Environment of an object

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Scope is often confusing in JavaScript - on the one hand,
> ```
>
> it can mean the object under which something is invoked (or executed), and on
>   the other it is the object under which something is defined. The
>   latter is referred to as lexical scope, and is considered the true
>   scope in JavaScript. Lexical scoping enables such programming
>   techniques as closures; for reference, take a look at this excellent
>   article by Richard Cornford.
>
> The idea of scope during invocation is known as the execution context in
>   JavaScript

This paragraph from the [dojo documentation website](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/hitch/)
was helpful for me. I Think it is a good resource regarding this question.

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia: "Namespaces are commonly structured as hierarchies to allow reuse of names in different contexts"

Let's say you have two namespace: "space" and "water"
Now let's say space has identifier "Ship". Let's also say that "water" has identifier "Ship".

Here we can reuse names but context will be different. So namespace is a declarative region that provides a scope to the identifiers and make this happen.

Java package for example organizes Javaclasses into namespaces.

In many languages local names in a function or method invocation has its own namespace. When a function is called, a local namespace is created for this function. This namespace is deleted either if the function ends, i.e. returns or throws error.